# How would you put a job which requires sudo to background?

Tags: sudo, background-process

I am looking for a way of putting a job which requires sudo to background, with as little interaction as possible except maybe typing my password.

sudo requires password from terminal, while background job will give up terminal:

```
$ sudo sleep 10 &
[1] 32749
$ fg 1
sudo sleep 10
[sudo] password for t:
```

My current solution is like above to type in my password, and then `bg 1` the job again. It requires me to interactively perform three commands

sudo only work with executables, not shell specific commands:

```
$ sudo ( sleep 10 & )
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `sleep'
$ sudo { sleep 10 & }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

The following way will detach the back ground job from the shell, undesirably:

```
$ sudo bash -c "sleep 10 & "
[sudo] password for t: 
$ jobs
$
```

I can also focus on `sudo`. For example, make the command NOPASSWD in sudoers, or take advantage of password cache by running a dummy sudo command ahead of my actual background sudo command. I am not sure if they are elegant ways. Let me know if any of them is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your last paragraph is the way to go about this. If disabling the password requirement is appropriate, then by all means configure the command with `NOPASSWD`. Otherwise, you can set things up ahead of time, if your `sudo` allows caching credentials (which it does by default):

```
sudo -v
sudo sleep 10 &
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `sudo -v` for this, as your "dummy sudo command ahead of an actual background sudo command"; the [sudo man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.25/sudo.man.html) gives this:

> By running sudo with the -v option, a user can update the cached credentials without running a command.

This doesn't require that the user have any other sudo-granted commands that would function as "dummy" sudo commands.