# Why is sudo's version worth protection?

Tags: sudo, version

I am surprised to see

```
$ sudo -v
[sudo] password for t:
```

Why is  its version worth protection?

Thanks.

Comment: **Always [check the man page](https://www.xkcd.com/293/) before assuming you know what an option flag does.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get sudo's version, use

```
sudo -V
```

This information is not protected, and does not require any sudoers privileges to execute (test with `sudo -k; sudo -V`).

As [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/479178/117549), `sudo -v` does something different.

A quick "meta" hack for finding version information:

```
man sudo | grep -i version
```

... which would result in (in part):

> -V, --version
>
> Print the sudo version string as well as the version string of the security policy plugin and any I/O

Answer (score 5):

`sudo -v` does not provide the version information .  `sudo -V` is the command for that.

Answer (score 3):

Because

```
sudo -v
```

does not print the version information; it instead **provides a way to the user to update the cached credentials without running an actual command**. So it's supposed to ask for the user's password.

The command to print sudo's **version** is

```
sudo -V
```